# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate keeps returning nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, formatting, nsdateformatter, null

I'm having a strange issue with a NSDateFormatter. Off course I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what it is, must be something small and stupid...

I have a date I want to format. The date is 2012-05-06 16:52:40 and is contained in an NSDate object, it is properly initialized, I checked that in the debugger.

The following code however:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myDate description]);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
NSString *myDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@", myDateAsString);
```

prints:

```
2012-05-06 16:52:40
(null)
```

I really don't see the error in my code. Any hints?

Comment: Can we see the initialisation code for `myDate`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`myDate` is actually an `NSString` and not an `NSDate`. Otherwise, the description would contain the time zone too: `2012-05-06 16:52:40 +0000`.

Try the following to check that:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myDate class]);
```

Comment: You're right :) In my code, where myDate's value was set, I didn't parse the incoming string to an NSDate object. What I don't really understand though is why there is no complaint from the compiler? And why does it appear as an NSDate instance in the debugger?

Comment: It appears as an instance of `NSDate` in the debugger because it was declared as such. Also, depending on how you assigned the value to `myDate`, the compiler could be unable to guess what type the value is and not show the warning. Something like `myDate = [array objectAtIndex:0];` is ok for the compiler even if the actual value was not an `NSDate`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It was coming from a JSON string that had been converted to an NSDictionary. Tnx!